# Weird infinite loop bug in jquery recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a strange issue on the project I'm working with. This changes an image source and a content of a div automatically.

I have coded a function, but it falls into infinite loop and page does not load (page is showing the loading page always).

These are the codes:

```
$.fn.extend({
    changehaber: function(a){
     $('#cokokunanlarcontent').fadeOut('slow',function() {
           $('.jquerycokokunanlarbutton').attr('src','images/sabah/buton-pasif.png');
           $('img[rel="'+a+'"]').attr('src','images/sabah/buton-aktif.png'); 
        }).html($('#'+a).html()).fadeIn('slow');
        return this;
    }
});

function slidecokokunanlar() {
    $('#cokokunanlarcontent').html($('#cokokunanlar1').html()).delay(3000).changehaber('cokokunanlar2').delay(3000).changehaber('cokokunanlar3').delay(3000).changehaber('cokokunanlar4').delay(3000).changehaber('cokokunanlar5').delay(3000);
    slidecokokunanlar();
}

slidecokokunanlar();
```

What's the issue here, when this is executed, I want the function to work infinitely, but the page shows it's always loading. This is the console's output:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call a function from inside itself without blocking up the whole execution stack. By calling the function from inside itself, you're effectively preventing it from ever returning, and as Javascript is single-threaded, everything will grind to a halt!

Change your function to this:

```
function slidecokokunanlar() {
    $('#cokokunanlarcontent').html($('#cokokunanlar1').html()).delay(3000)...
    setTimeout(slidecokokunanlar, 0);
}
```

This allows for concurrent execution without blocking the UI, thus allowing your page to remain responsive.

See [this article on "chunking"](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/) for more information on how this works.

Comment: You got the "setTimeout" arguments backwards, and the function name should not be in quotes.

Comment: It may get rid of the error, but you're still recursively calling the function at an insanely fast rate.

Comment: I've experienced this same thing even though I used `setTimeout`;  seemed like it was the best option.  I wonder if `setInterval` in a different context would make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

This is because [JavaScript doesn't have proper tail calls](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/javascript-is-dead-long-live-javascript).

Your function calls itself at the end of itself forever. The first one never finishes and returns, nor does the second, nor do any of them until you run out of stack and explode.

You might try using `setTimeout` instead. See an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5JzU/1/).

**EDIT** You might not want to use 0 unless you really need it to be running continuously. Even using 100, you'd execute the function 10 times per second.

```
function foo(){
  console.log('foo');
  setTimeout(foo, 0);  
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner way to do it.

```
var coko = $('#cokokunanlarcontent');             // cokokunanlarcontent
var cokos = $('[id^="cokokunanlar"]').not(coko);  // cokokunanlar1..2..3 etc

var total = cokos.length;  // total quantity

var i = 0;

var allow = true;

$('.jquerycokokunanlarbutton').attr('src','images/sabah/buton-pasif.png');

function slidecokokunanlar( isRestart ) {

    if( !isRestart ) {
        $('img[rel="' + cokos[i].id + '"]').attr('src','images/sabah/buton-aktif.png');

        coko.html( cokos.eq(i).html() )
            .fadeIn( 'slow' );
    }
    if( allow ) {
        coko.delay( 3000 )
            .fadeOut('slow', function() {
               i = (++i % total);
               slidecokokunanlar();  // recursively call with next index or 0
            });
    }
}

slidecokokunanlar();  // start it off

function restartSlider() { 
    allow = true;
    slidecokokunanlar( true );
}

function stopSlider() { 
    allow = false;
}

stopSlider();   // to stop it

restartSlider();  // to restart it
```

Comment: Thanks, I've also thought about this, but the images which I'm changing will have to stop the function (the changing of animation), which I'm doing by (clearTimeout(variable)), which variable is "var variable = setTimeout(functionname,0);" and I could not manage it doing it using a similar method. How's that possible with your method ?

Comment: @Arda: Just have a flag that is checked each time the recursive function call is to run, like `var allow = true;`. The variable will of course need to be outside the `slidecokounalar()` function. When you want to stop the recursion, set the flag to `false`. To start it again, set the flag to `true`, and call `slidecokounalar()`. If you want it to pick up where it left off, place the `i` in a variable outside the function, and update it each time instead of passing it as an argument. I'll update my answer to implement these ideas.

Comment: Updated. I gave `slidecokokunanlar();` a special `isRestart` parameter so that if it is being restarted (as opposed to the first time it is started) it won't try to load and `fadeIn` the content that is already showing.